# Using forward slash in query

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I want this

```
www.example.com/?category=electronics&gadget=mouse
```

to look like this:

```
www.example.com/?electronics/mouse
```

I pull data by doing `XHR` request with normal queries. But I want the filter queries to be shown in `URL` in most readable way by using `history.pushState()`. And also it should stay at the same page when reloading.

1. Is it possible for browsers to come back to same page when reloading? I mean not only most modern but most of them.

Attention, there is "?" after "/" in the second url.

Comment: You will need a server-side setup, that does the necessary URL rewriting, and returns all the necessary code to render the specific view requested via those URLs.

Comment: @CBroe I edited my answer. Please, see the "?" after "/". Can a query string contain "/" safely? How do browsers render it? I don't want any server-side action.

Comment: Server-side rendering is still the basis for most of the things you are asking for here. (Same content shown after hard reload, readability of your content for search engine robots in the first place.)

Comment: If it's strictly to follow the URL requirement, technically this is possible on the client-side since the URL query is accessible in Javascript, and an XHR request is being done.

Comment: Might I add, if I understand it correctly, the URL example you've shown is the URL seen by the browser's address bar?

Comment: @Mike Yes, it is the one that is shown in address bar. So, is writing forward slash after question mark okay? I was worried about SEO as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the current URL and parse out the text after the `?`.

```js
const query = location.href.split("?").pop()
```

This splits the current URL by each `?` and returns the last item.

Then you can retrieve the parameters by its structure.

```js
const [category, gadget] = query.split("/")
```

This assigns the first and second index of the query split by `/` to the variables `category` and `gadget` respectively. That's the same as doing this.

```js
var parts = query.split("/")
var category = parts[0]
var gadget = parts[1]
```

With these two variables, you can pass in the correct data in your `XHR` request.

As for the history request, as long as you run the `XHR` request on load, your page will reflect the correct information each time. You can also read up on [Window popstate events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) to detect changes in `history`.

EDIT: Only read now about the concern with SEO. There isn't much you can do with SEO with this approach since most SEO crawlers don't run Javascript when parsing information. Having Javascript inject meta would prove useless for most crawlers. Sorry. As  CBroe said, you'd need server-side rendering for this.